# Dashboard grid layout broken after an auto update gone wrong

Tags: auto-updates, dashboard

An auto update went awry. I lost Internet connection towards the end of the update. Each widget now appears on its own row. Everything else looks ok on the front end as well as the admin. When I check for updates, it says I'm up to date. Does anyone have any suggestions as to which files I should update to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache of your browser?

Comment: It was as simple as that. Thank you Michael.

Comment: Can you add that as the official answer, @AneJoh?

Comment: Answer added. Glad it worked @AneJoh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your browser cache. (Your browser might be holding onto a stylesheet or something from the previous version.)